# SQL - Compare and Update table for rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, for example:

```
Table firstfile                      Table secondfile
===============                      ================

Emplid   | Color                     Emplid       | Color   |status
-------------------                  -------------|---------|------
123      | red                       123          | red     |
456      | green                     456          | Green   |
789      | black                     000          | red     | 
777      | orange                    789          | black   |
                                     999          | white   |
```

Table `firstfile` is my source table and `secondfile` is the destination table. Now I need a query which finds all the rows in `firstfile` that does not exist in table `secondfile`. So I need a query which finds me the following:

```
Table secondfile
================
Emplid       | Color   | Status
-------------------------------
123          | red     |
456          | Green   |
000          | red     | 
789          | black   |
999          | white   | 
777          | orange  | Removed
```

What is a good approach for such a query in `CASE WHEN` format?

I tried this but it's not working:

```
UPDATE second file 
set status = (CASE 
                 WHEN first file.Emplid not In (select Emplid 
                                               from secondfile) 
                    THEN 'Remove' 
              END);
```

Comment: Do you need an `update` query or a `select` query?

Comment: @user3378165 i want to update those records which are present in firstfile but not in secondfile. Also the status of such records in secondfile should be as 'removed'

Comment: Your question is not clear, so be more explicit please !

Comment: What is not working in your query?

Comment: @SharikDokadia you can not update secondfile if the record does not exist in it. don't you mean to update firstfile, if does not exist in secondfile?

Comment: Do you mean insert a record which not exit in second widh status 'Removed'?

Comment: @Amazigh.Ca yes

Comment: @user3378165 i want to insert a record which does not exist in secondfile with status 'Removed'

Comment: @Stephen i want to insert a record which does not exist in secondfile with status 'Removed'

Comment: @SharikDokadia okay, you can take your pick on the provided answers, they do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not `UPDATE` a row that doesn't exist, you can `INSERT` a new row.

You can do it with the `NOT IN` function:

```
INSERT INTO secondfile
SELECT  f.Emplid,f.Color, 'Removed' 
FROM    firstfile f
WHERE   f.Emplid NOT IN (SELECT 1 FROM secondfile s WHERE f.Emplid=s.Emplid)
```

Or with the `NOT EXISTS` function:

```
INSERT INTO secondfile
SELECT f.Emplid,f.Color, 'Removed'
FROM firstfile f 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT s.Emplid FROM secondfile s)
```

You can also do it with a `JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO secondfile
SELECT f.Emplid,f.Color, 'Removed'
FROM firstfile f 
LEFT OUTER JOIN secondfile s ON f.Emplid = s.Emplid 
WHERE s.Emplid IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. The query with JOIN worked. however, first two has some errors as follows: –

with NOT IN, error is Duplicate entry '352679' for key 'PRIMARY'

with NOT EXIST there's no error but the output does not have a single removed in status column

Answer (score 0):

I think you are actually looking for an `INSERT` rather than an `UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO secondfile (Emplid, Color, Status)
SELECT EmplId, Color, 'Removed' 
FROM firstfile AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM secondfile AS t2
                  WHERE t1.Emplid = t2.Emplid AND t1.Color = t2.Color)
```

Comment: i tried that but all the records have their status column as 'removed'

Comment: @Sharik I thought this was your intention

Comment: No Sir, i want to insert a record which does not exist in secondfile with status 'Removed'

but with this query i get all records which were already present as 'removed'